# Receive Angular2 POST with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have this method:

```
gotoDispatch() {
    // 
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var url = 'Users/Cards';
    var dto = { 'jsonSearchCards': 'testing' };

    return this.http.post(GlobalVariables.SITE_ROOT + url, dto, { headers })
        .subscribe(function (data) {
        console.log('received response');
    });
}
```

In my ASP.net controller I have:

```
var currentForm = Request.Form["jsonSearchCards"];
var from = Request.Params["jsonSearchCards"];
```

but both receive null? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object on the .NET side that matches the object you're sending from JavaScript.

```
public class TheRequest
{
    public string JsonSearchCards { get; set; }
}
```

Then make that the parameter to your API method.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ASP.NET question, not an Angular 2 one.

Just add the variables to signature of your controller method:

```
public IHttpActionResult FindParts(string JsonSearchCards)
{
}
```